# Looping through certain elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop through certain elements in React as i need to render part of an array per each view.

Array rendering has to start from ArrayIndexStart and end at ArrayIndexEnd.

Here is what i got:

```js
var ObjectArray =[{"letter":"a"},{"letter":"b"},{"letter":"c"},{"letter":"d"},{"letter":"e"},{"letter":"f"},{"letter":"g"},{"letter":"h"},{"letter":"i"},{"letter":"j"},{"letter":"k"},{"letter":"l"},{"letter":"ł"},{"letter":"m"},{"letter":"n"},{"letter":"ń"},{"letter":"o"},{"letter":"ó"},{"letter":"p"},{"letter":"q"},{"letter":"r"},{"letter":"s"},{"letter":"ś"},{"letter":"t"},{"letter":"u"},{"letter":"v"},{"letter":"w"},{"letter":"x"},{"letter":"y"},{"letter":"z"},{"letter":"ź"},{"letter":"ż"}];

class ImageViewer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            ArrayIndexStart: 0,
            ArrayIndexEnd: 8,
        }
        this.handleButtonLeft = this.handleButtonLeft.bind(this);
        this.handleButtonRight = this.handleButtonRight.bind(this);
    }
    handleButtonLeft(ArrayIndexStart, ArrayIndexEnd, event) {
        if (ArrayIndexStart >= 8) {
            this.setState({ ArrayIndexEnd: ArrayIndexEnd,ArrayIndexStart: ArrayIndexStart})
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ ArrayIndexEnd: 8,ArrayIndexStart: 0 })
        }
    }
    handleButtonRight(ArrayIndexStart, ArrayIndexEnd, event) { 
        if (ArrayIndexEnd <= ObjectArray.length) {
            this.setState({ ArrayIndexStart: ArrayIndexStart,ArrayIndexEnd: ArrayIndexEnd })
        }
        else  {
            this.setState({ ArrayIndexStart: 24,ArrayIndexEnd: ObjectArray.length })
        }
    }
    render() {
     return(
         
         <div>
         <button onClick={() => this.handleButtonLeft(this.state.ArrayIndexStart - 8, this.state.ArrayIndexEnd - 8)}>left</button>     
         <button onClick={() => this.handleButtonRight(this.state.ArrayIndexStart + 8, this.state.ArrayIndexEnd + 8)}>right</button>
         <div>
                   <p>{this.state.ArrayIndexStart}</p>
                    <p>{this.state.ArrayIndexEnd}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
     )
        for(var i = this.state.ArrayIndexStart;i<this.state.ArrayIndexEnd;i++)
        {
            return(
                <div>
                <p>{ObjectArray[i].letter}</p>
                </div>
            )
        }


     
    }}
    ReactDOM.render(
    <ImageViewer  />,
    document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```

I made this this code but double return type doesn't work and it is not possible to return more than 1 element from this for loop.
I am not sure how to make it to work.

Comment: no need for separate `setState` calls, can do the setting in the same call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code after your first return statement from `render()` is ignored - once the function had returned then its execution stops.  It is often useful to use a tool like ESLint which can tell you when this is the case and guide you to writing better code.

In your case then you could loop over the ObjectArray with a `for` loop to create the elements you need, but it is much easier to use some functional programming techniques to do this within your JSX.

I have updated your snippet to show one way of doing this.  It uses the slice function first:

```
ObjectArray.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
```

which returns a new array containing only the elements between start and end index.  For example,

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].slice(1, 3); // returns [2,3,4]
```

Once we have sliced the part of the array that we need, we can then use the `map` function to transform each element of the array into the form that we need.

```
ObjectArray.map(obj => obj.letter);
```

The map function takes a single argument (the lambda function `obj => obj.letter`) which will be applied in turn to each member of the array.

A simpler example might be doubling each number in an array:

```
[1,2,3,4].map(x => x * 2); // returns [2,4,6,8];
```

I have also made some changes to simplify your click handler functions.  It uses the functional setState argument, i.e.

```
this.setState(previousState => {
    return {
        // state update object
    }
});
```

This is the correct approach to use when your next state depends on the value of your previous state - in your code the next index depends on the value of the previous index.  It also greatly simplifies the JSX by allowing you to do:

```
onClick={this.handleButtonClick(increment)}
```

For both buttons, passing a negative increment to go "left" and a positive increment to go "right".

```js
var ObjectArray =[{"letter":"a"},{"letter":"b"},{"letter":"c"},{"letter":"d"},{"letter":"e"},{"letter":"f"},{"letter":"g"},{"letter":"h"},{"letter":"i"},{"letter":"j"},{"letter":"k"},{"letter":"l"},{"letter":"ł"},{"letter":"m"},{"letter":"n"},{"letter":"ń"},{"letter":"o"},{"letter":"ó"},{"letter":"p"},{"letter":"q"},{"letter":"r"},{"letter":"s"},{"letter":"ś"},{"letter":"t"},{"letter":"u"},{"letter":"v"},{"letter":"w"},{"letter":"x"},{"letter":"y"},{"letter":"z"},{"letter":"ź"},{"letter":"ż"}];

class ImageViewer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            ArrayIndexStart: 0,
            ArrayIndexEnd: 8
        };
        this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleButtonClick(increment) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            if (prevState.ArrayIndexStart + increment >= 8 && 
                prevState.ArrayIndexEnd + increment <=
                ObjectArray.length) {
                return {
                    ArrayIndexEnd: prevState.ArrayIndexEnd + increment,
                    ArrayIndexStart: prevState.ArrayIndexStart + increment
                };
            } else if (increment < 0) {
                return {
                    ArrayIndexEnd: 8,
                    ArrayIndexStart: 0
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    ArrayIndexEnd: ObjectArray.length,
                    ArrayIndexStart: ObjectArray.length - increment
                }
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
     return(
         
         <div>
         <button onClick={() => this.handleButtonClick(-8)}>left</button>     
         <button onClick={() => this.handleButtonClick(8)}>right</button>
         <div>
                   <p>{this.state.ArrayIndexStart}</p>
                    <p>{this.state.ArrayIndexEnd}</p>
        </div>

        {ObjectArray.slice(this.state.ArrayIndexStart, this.state.ArrayIndexEnd
         ).map(obj => obj.letter)
         }
        </div>
     )


     
    }}
    ReactDOM.render(
    <ImageViewer  />,
    document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help - I have edited my answer with some other changes that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

No a return statement ends where the return is made, so you can't return twice and hope to see both, the render function will stop after the first return.

An easy `.map()` function to iterate and return each object to your render function, this will be your golden key here. consider this code:

```
render() {
    return <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleButtonLeft(this.state.ArrayIndexStart - 8, this.state.ArrayIndexEnd - 8)}>left</button>     
        <button onClick={() => this.handleButtonRight(this.state.ArrayIndexStart + 8, this.state.ArrayIndexEnd + 8)}>right</button>
        <div>
            <p>{this.state.ArrayIndexStart}</p>
            <p>{this.state.ArrayIndexEnd}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            {ObjectArray.slice(this.state.ArrayIndexStart, this.state.ArrayIndexEnd).map(item => {
                return <p>{item.letter}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I don't want to render whole Object Array but start from ArrayIndexStart and end on ArrayIndexEnd.

Comment: Thanks for input.

Comment: You might be able to use .slice() and then .map().

Comment: @RobWelan thats a really good advice! just updated my answer, because `.slice()` is chainable is really easy to add it before the map.